# How to figure out which algorithm MATLAB selects when mldivide is called

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

When I call `mldivide` of MATLAB like below, I want to know which [algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt4jslc-6) MATLAB selects for my input matrix. How can I do that?

```
k_inv = mldivide(k,eye(size(k)));
```

Comment: The flowchart you link describes it, right? You would just need a few `if`s to arrive at the same conclusion as `mldivide`. I agree that it would be easier if the selected algorithm were an additional output of `mldivide`, though

Comment: @LuisMendo I found something [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1459), but looks like it only works for sparse matrices. Probably I will have to use `if` conditions.